# activate MCC, MNC API in Nokia Pys60

Tags: mobile, nokia, pys60

I can not get location info from pyS60. It seems the featured API is not activated.

How can I activate this API? Is there any free licensing system?

Or anything so that I can use restricted (or non-free for general developers) APIs at least in my phone to test the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign you application. The process depends on the phone and kind of developement model you want to follow.

If you just want to test some apps on your phone, use [Open Signed Online](http://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do). If you want to test many small scripts, perhaps it is better to sign the PythonShell itself.

I've done something similar, you can get more info at [nokia-gsm-location-hacks](http://code.google.com/p/nokia-gsm-location-hacks/wiki/Howto) howto.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I simply couldn't find this simple solution anywhere directly. People (far wiser than me) have done lots of complex stuffs which I am not capable to get clearly.